# Change the Starting Point on Bezier Curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

A Bezier Curve was generated by a Text to Curve operation.  Active Spline Cyclic U was chosen by this operation.  The Curve appears closed just as most text glyphs do.

Now I would like to change the starting point on the curve.  Actions taken

- closing the curve (Which seems to be detected by Blender and maybe defeated)
- making two adjoining points buttressing  the destination point
- deleting destination point

So far this attempt has failed.  What actions should be taken?

I have hand edited this as a workaround yet this is not a half ideal situation.

Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer in the linked duplicate with additional methods